# Someone can help me with a error on my query type select

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REPLACE(CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.user, '[', '') , ']', '') , '"', '')),'0,','')) as email
    from car a
    INNER JOIN pct b on b.id = a.idcarr
    where irt = 1.3.4 AND b.id = 96
```

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.4 AND b.id = 96 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4

Comment: `irt = 1.3.4` should be `irt = '1.3.4'`

Comment: $irt = $_REQUEST['irt'];    where irt = $irt  AND b.id = $idcar";     What should I do here?

Comment: Put single quotes around `$irt`: `where irt = '$irt'`

Comment: You should use prepared statements. That will save you from this sort of issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php